# How to pass a variable from one class to another class?

Tags: python, class, variables, instance

I'm new to python and recently developing an app with kivy. Right now I'm trying to pass a variable a method creates in one class to the next class, but can't figure out how to do so.

Here's my first class, that basically just shows me which of three togglebuttons is currently pushed down:

```
class InputParameters(GridLayout):

    verfahren = ObjectProperty(None)

    def on_state(self, togglebutton):
        tb = togglebutton
        if tb.state == 'down':
            self.verfahren = tb.text
            print(self.verfahren)
            return self.verfahren
```

I get the value that's selected, so the method is working, now I'm trying to instance the selected value in this class, but I'm not sure how:

```
class StatusBar(BoxLayout):
    #InputGrößen
    group_mode = False
    prozess = ObjectProperty(None)
    vorbehandlung = ObjectProperty(None)
    material = ObjectProperty(None)
    haerte = ObjectProperty(None)
    rauheit = ObjectProperty(None)

    def btn_submit(self):

        ip = App.get_running_app().root.ids._input_parameters
        op = App.get_running_app().root.ids._output_parameters

        print("Haerte:", ip.haerte.value, "Rauheit:", ip.rauheit.value, "Material:", ip.material.text, "Vorbehandlung:", ip.vorbehandlung.text)
```

In a first step I only want to print the values to my console when pressing a submit button. That's working for the shown code. But I can't figure out how to use my variable `verfahren` in the method `btn_submit` of the `class(StatusBar(BoxLayout)`. I hope you can help, this should rather be easy but I'm an absolute greenhorn...

Comment: You should do a tutorial on OOP in Python. Your code does not reflect how it is done.

Comment: Use `InputParameters.verfahren`

Comment: Thanks for the advice, but I did a couple before starting to implement the app in Python and kivy. But I guess like always everything is easier in theory...
Of course it doesn't reflect how it's done. I'm asking for advice, not telling the solution.

Comment: @PatrikPolakovic tried that before, if I do so I get as an Output: <ObjectProperty name=verfahren>